# How to render water particles animation (and reconstruct a surface from particles)?

Tags: rendering, materials, particles

I have an Alembic file(.abc) containing animation of fluid particles. When I import it to Blender, the animation works fine but it just does not have any visual effects, as shown in the following figure.
[image]

[image]

The animation shows a water ball falling to the ground.

As I am very new to blender, I am wondering if there is a way to add water material to these particles and render them into a realistic photo. And furthermore, I am also wondering if there is a way to reconstruct a surface mesh using Blender from these particles?

I've tried to modify its material but it seems I am going wrong.
[image]